# Powershell remove random digits from string

Tags: powershell, csv

This should be simple but its driving me crazy. I have a csv with a column for example

$data

Ho-me1234

Ho-me345667

Ho-me32123556

I cant figure out how to replace or trim the random numbers off the end of Ho-me because I don't understand the wildcard part. I have read and tried a ton of examples but cant seem to get anything to work. How do I declare the wildcard in front of the text HO-ME?

**update** I cannot remove all numbers from the CSV there are numbers in the CSV I need to keep.

Comment: Example: `"Ho-me23442" -replace '\d+$',''`

Comment: $data | % { $_.Trim('1234567890')}

Comment: Im sorry I should have been more clear I cant remove all numbers in the csv blindly theres numbers in the CSV I neet to keep. 

Bill_stewart the numbers are random so I cant call out "Ho-me23442"

Comment: @doobis loop over the csv rows and apply the `-replace '\d+$',''` operation to the column in question on each

Comment: Hi, please provide a sample input file and desired output. [You can edit your question to add information](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41385873/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds from the comments like your input file doesn't look like you describe in the question. Assuming your csv looks more like this:

```
OtherColumn,InterestingColumn
62812974831,Ho-me1234
13021568343,Ho-me345667
25166647926,Ho-me32123556
```

pipe it to `ForEach-Object` and apply the `-replace` operation [suggested by Bill_Stewart in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385873/powershell-remove-random-digits-from-string#comment69973981_41385873):

```
Import-Csv .\input.csv |ForEach-Object {
    $_.InterestingColumn = $_.InterestingColumn -replace '\d+$',''
    $_
} |Export-Csv .\output.csv
```

You can split it into two separate statements to overwrite the input file:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\input.csv
$data |ForEach-Object {
    $_.InterestingColumn = $_.InterestingColumn -replace '\d+$',''
    $_
} |Export-Csv .\input.csv -Force
```

The regex pattern is simply:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - at the end of the string

Comment: That worked!!! but just wondering is there a way to keep it in the same file? If not that's fine. Also could you explain how that fixed it?